# PHP skipping over XMLWriter::endElement()

Tags: php, xmlwriter

I am having an issue, while using the PHP XMLWriter extension.
I have a perfectly functional script extracting valid XML from an old CentOS 5 server. Recently I started to plan migration to CentOS7 and then the very same script skips over the XMLWritter::endElement(), therefore not closing any element when asked. In the end, PHP starts to close them automatically, because in fact they all remain open.

```
        $writer->startElement( 'element1' );
            $writer->text('1');
        $writer->endElement('element1');
        $writer->startElement( 'element2' );
            $writer->text('2');
        $writer->endElement('element2');
        $writer->startElement( 'element3' );
            $writer->text('3');
        $writer->endElement('element3');
        $writer->startElement( 'element4' );
            $writer->text('4');
        $writer->endElement('element4');
```

I get a big tree of nested elements:

```
<element1>1
    <element2>2
        <element3>3
            <element4>4
               ...
            </element4>
        </element3>
    </element2>  
</element1>
```

anyone knows why is this?

Answer (score 1):

`XMLWriter->endElement()` expects no arguments and is failing.

Use this instead:

```php
$writer->startElement('element1');
$writer->text('1');
$writer->endElement();
$writer->startElement('element2');
$writer->text('2');
$writer->endElement();
$writer->startElement('element3');
$writer->text('3');
$writer->endElement();
$writer->startElement('element4');
$writer->text('4');
$writer->endElement();
```

or more succinctly, use `writeElement()` if you are not using attributes:

```php
$writer->writeElement('element1', '1');
$writer->writeElement('element2', '2');
$writer->writeElement('element3', '3');
$writer->writeElement('element4', '4');
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted and/or not accepted as it is the correct answer.